# Undefined document field value even inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore, and trying to extract the "isSeller: true" field from a document "user".

```
function StorefrontPage(props) {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const uid = auth.user && auth.user.uid;


  useEffect(() => {
    uid && getUser(uid).then(currentUser => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    })
    console.log(user.isSeller);
  }, [auth, router])

  console.log(user.isSeller);
```

However, both console logs will initially return "true" which is what I want, but then upon refreshes and page changes, will revert back to undefined. I thought putting the console.log inside of the useEffect would fix my issue, but it doesn't. I know it has to do with asynchronous functions, but I thought useEffect fixes that issue of data not arriving yet.

For reference, the getUser function looks like this:

```
export function getUser(uid) {
  return firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get().then(user => {
    return user.data();
  })
}
```

This part works fine.
Any ideas how to fix this.

Comment: Why are `auth` and `router` in the effect hook's dependency array, they aren't referenced in the hook callback? When do you want that effect hook to be triggered?

Comment: I think you need to watch user also inside useEffect() second arg. Because along with your route, your user data gets undefined again and when it get's updated your useEffect() needs to be informed. So either you can separate the useEffect() for user data or add user alone with auth and router as 2nd arg to useEffect()

Comment: if they're getting empty on refresh, try to output `auth` and `router` to see what has changed. Most likely `auth` is doing something unexpected, so I'm guessing you'll need to check `useAuth`

Comment: @DrewReese I removed the auth, router dependency - got the same issue.

Comment: @Mohit Even after deleting the auth, router dependency, I'm still getting this issue.

Comment: @IvanSatsiuk Even after deleting the auth, router dependency, I'm still getting this issue.

Comment: @Mohit can you expand on your answer a bit?

Comment: I was saying that could you add another useEffect() to check if your user data is updated then you can set your state inside that useEffect()